# Bash: given a list of arguments separated by newline, how to pass all of them to another process?

Tags: bash, command-line, xargs

A little backstory, because maybe my approach is fundamentally wrong:

Currently I'm trying to make a pre-commit script that checks what files where changed and passes them to a linter. Here's what I currently have:

```
STAGED=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep -E "\.js$")
echo "${STAGED}" | xargs -I {} eslint {}
```

This does work, but it has a flaw: it launches a new process for each file and, as you can imagine, the delay is noticeably large when given multiple files (and yes, launching this process on the whole folder manually doesn't take as long as launching it 20+ times on single files).

I tried passing `-n $(echo ${STAGED} | wc -l)` to xargs, but that changed nothing.

I also tried to do this:

```
eslint $(echo ${STAGED} | sed -E "s/^(.*)$/\"\1\"/g" | tr "\n" " ")
```

Quotes are there to make sure that files with whitespace are treated properly. But this did not work at all.

Another thing I tried is changing `IFS`:

```
OLD_IFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n'
eslint "${STAGED}"
IFS="${OLD_IFS}"
```

That also did not work for me at all.

Is there a decent solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not change `eslint` to read filenames from `stdin` instead of processing *positional parameters*? You could then pipe (or since you tagged bash use *process substitution*) to feed all the filenames to it in the original newline separated format? E.g. `while read -r fname; do eslint "$fname"; done < <(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep -E "\.js$")` or just pipe the output of `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep -E "\.js$" | eslint`? Hard to tell without seeing `eslint`.

Comment: As an aside, all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; the POSIX specification guarantees that compliance shells and tools treat lowercase variable names as reserved for application use -- so while shell variables with all-caps names can override a shell-builtin variable or an environment variable that standard tools read, using lowercase names for your own variables is safe from conflicts with POSIX-y tools. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: I do `git diff --name-only --cached | grep -E '(.js|.jsx)$' | xargs eslint` without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're  on a platform with GNU grep, consider:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -z |
  grep -zZ '[.]js$' |
  xargs -0 eslint
```

...on non-GNU platforms, this could instead be:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -z |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do [[ $name = *.js ]] && printf '%s\0' "$name"; done |
  xargs -0 eslint
```

**The most important change here is not using `xargs -I`, which implies `-n 1`.**

Using `git diff -z`, `grep -zZ`, and `xargs -0` separates your filenames with NUL bytes, meaning that even names with newline literals will be handled correctly. (`git` may disallow these, but they're generally permissible on UNIX systems as a whole, so making a habit of handling them safely is good hygiene).

---

Another approach to this is to read the results of your command into an array. Assuming a sufficiently new (4.4) version of bash, and that your list of files isn't larger than would fit on a single command line (which would require `xargs`):

```
readarray -d '' changed_files < <(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -z)
eslint "${changed_files[@]}"
```

Comment: This is flawless, thanks. The fact that `-I` implies `-n 1` is a bit questionable. What if I wanted to add some constant arguments afterwards? For example, eslint's `--fix` would attempt to automatically fix code formatting, but it needs to be put after file names.

Comment: @LilithW.Green, that's poor (standards-noncompliant) design on ESLint's part -- see Guideline 9 in the POSIX utility syntax guidelines at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html; options should always precede positional arguments. GNU tools do allow the inverse ordering, but they *permit* the compliant one, and support `--` as an end-of-options separator (which makes it possible to pass positional arguments which might otherwise be parsed as options); both of these mitigate the impact of that noncompliance.

Comment: @LilithW.Green, ...that said, one way to work around it as follows: `xargs -0 sh -c 'exec eslint "$@" --fix' _`